# styling a JS variable

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is some code I found, and it works fine. My question is how to style the one part of it that says 'Christmas!'. Say I want to make it red or green, while the rest of the countdown has the style from the css 'input' below.

```js
//change the text below to reflect your own,
var before = "Christmas!"
var current = "Today is Christmas. Merry Christmas!"
var montharray = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")

function countdown(yr, m, d) {
    theyear = yr;
    themonth = m;
    theday = d
    var today = new Date()
    var todayy = today.getYear()
    if (todayy < 1000)
      todayy += 1900
    var todaym = today.getMonth()
    var todayd = today.getDate()
    var todayh = today.getHours()
    var todaymin = today.getMinutes()
    var todaysec = today.getSeconds()
    var todaystring = montharray[todaym] + " " + todayd + ", " + todayy + " " + todayh + ":" + todaymin + ":" + todaysec
    futurestring = montharray[m - 1] + " " + d + ", " + yr
    dd = Date.parse(futurestring) - Date.parse(todaystring)
    dday = Math.floor(dd / (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24) * 1)
    dhour = Math.floor((dd % (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24)) / (60 * 60 * 1000) * 1)
    dmin = Math.floor(((dd % (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24)) % (60 * 60 * 1000)) / (60 * 1000) * 1)
    dsec = Math.floor((((dd % (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24)) % (60 * 60 * 1000)) % (60 * 1000)) / 1000 * 1)
    if (dday == 0 && dhour == 0 && dmin == 0 && dsec == 1) {
      document.forms.count.count2.value = current
      return
    } else
      document.forms.count.count2.value = "Only " + dday + " days, " + dhour + " hours, " + dmin + " minutes, and " + dsec + " seconds left until " + before
    setTimeout("countdown(theyear,themonth,theday)", 1000)
  }
  //enter the count down date using the format year/month/day
countdown(2016, 12, 25)
```

```css
input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 135px;
  width: 1000px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #21247A;
  border: none;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
}
```

```html
<div class="countdown">
  <form name="count">
    <input type="text" size="69" name="count2">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Normally this would be really easy, because your text is being shown within an input tag, I don't believe it is possible to color only *some* of the text.

Comment: Is there a reason this a `<input>`? Why not use a `<div>`? Then you could wrap portions of text with a `<span>` and style accordingly.

Comment: It doesnt have to be anything. if there is a better way that gets to my goal, please let me know! would I put the 'span' tag in the 'var' declaration in the JS?

Comment: sou you just copy/paste the code but did you understand it ?

Comment: I understood the code, just asking if I can style a variable while it's being declared, which according to the answer below, is the case indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless otherwise required, I would move it out of an `<input>` and into a `<div>`. Which is what I've done, along with wrapping *Christmas!* in a span and styling.

If you try to use the `<input>` with HTML it will not work as intended as the markup won't be rendered as HTML but rather text.

```js
//change the text below to reflect your own,
var before = '<span class="day">Christmas!</span>'
var current = "Today is Christmas. Merry Christmas!"
var montharray = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
var container = document.querySelector('.countdown');

function countdown(yr, m, d) {
    theyear = yr;
    themonth = m;
    theday = d
    var today = new Date()
    var todayy = today.getYear()
    if (todayy < 1000)
      todayy += 1900
    var todaym = today.getMonth()
    var todayd = today.getDate()
    var todayh = today.getHours()
    var todaymin = today.getMinutes()
    var todaysec = today.getSeconds()
    var todaystring = montharray[todaym] + " " + todayd + ", " + todayy + " " + todayh + ":" + todaymin + ":" + todaysec
    futurestring = montharray[m - 1] + " " + d + ", " + yr
    dd = Date.parse(futurestring) - Date.parse(todaystring)
    dday = Math.floor(dd / (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24) * 1)
    dhour = Math.floor((dd % (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24)) / (60 * 60 * 1000) * 1)
    dmin = Math.floor(((dd % (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24)) % (60 * 60 * 1000)) / (60 * 1000) * 1)
    dsec = Math.floor((((dd % (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24)) % (60 * 60 * 1000)) % (60 * 1000)) / 1000 * 1)
    if (dday == 0 && dhour == 0 && dmin == 0 && dsec == 1) {
      container.innerHTML = current
      return
    } else
      container.innerHTML = "Only " + dday + " days, " + dhour + " hours, " + dmin + " minutes, and " + dsec + " seconds left until " + before
    setTimeout( function () {
      countdown( theyear, themonth, theday );
    }, 1000)
  }
  //enter the count down date using the format year/month/day
countdown(2016, 12, 25)
```

```css
.countdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 135px;
  width: 1000px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #21247A;
  border: none;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
}
.countdown .day {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="countdown"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the response.

Answer (score 2):

try with `p tag` `<p id="text" size="69" name="count2"></p>`

Declare the var like `var before = "<span style='color:red;'>Christmas!</span>"`

```js
//change the text below to reflect your own,
var before = "<span style='color:red;'>Christmas!</span>"
var current = "Today is Christmas. Merry Christmas!"
var montharray = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")

function countdown(yr, m, d) {
    theyear = yr;
    themonth = m;
    theday = d
    var today = new Date()
    var todayy = today.getYear()
    if (todayy < 1000)
      todayy += 1900
    var todaym = today.getMonth()
    var todayd = today.getDate()
    var todayh = today.getHours()
    var todaymin = today.getMinutes()
    var todaysec = today.getSeconds()
    var todaystring = montharray[todaym] + " " + todayd + ", " + todayy + " " + todayh + ":" + todaymin + ":" + todaysec
    futurestring = montharray[m - 1] + " " + d + ", " + yr
    dd = Date.parse(futurestring) - Date.parse(todaystring)
    dday = Math.floor(dd / (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24) * 1)
    dhour = Math.floor((dd % (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24)) / (60 * 60 * 1000) * 1)
    dmin = Math.floor(((dd % (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24)) % (60 * 60 * 1000)) / (60 * 1000) * 1)
    dsec = Math.floor((((dd % (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24)) % (60 * 60 * 1000)) % (60 * 1000)) / 1000 * 1)
    if (dday == 0 && dhour == 0 && dmin == 0 && dsec == 1) {
       document.getElementById('text').innerHTML= current
      return
    } else
      document.getElementById('text').innerHTML= "Only " + dday + " days, " + dhour + " hours, " + dmin + " minutes, and " + dsec + " seconds left until " + before
    setTimeout("countdown(theyear,themonth,theday)", 1000)
  }
  //enter the count down date using the format year/month/day
countdown(2016, 12, 25)
```

```css
p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 135px;
  width: 1000px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #21247A;
  border: none;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
}
```

```html
<div class="countdown">
  <form name="count">
    <p id="text" size="69" name="count2"></p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: ok, so I can style it directly in the variable declaration?  That is really all I needed to know. Thanks!

Comment: try this `style='color:red;'` see the updated answer .apply the style directly with `var`

Comment: @scott.schaffer note that you can't change the variable and **not** change the elements (that is, keep using `<input>`).

Comment: Also, FWIW, `size` and `name` are not valid attributes for a `<p>`.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a HTML tag like this

```
     document.getElementById("divElementforChristmas").innerHTML = "<h1 class='ChristmasColorClass'>+before+</h1>";
```

this will put h1 tag under a div having ID = divElementforChristmas and its class will be ChristmasColorClass so you can modify a portion or you can create new element by using following

```
    document.createElement("h1")
```

Comment: Why would you use an `h1` for just the day portion of the string? `<span>` would be ideal in vast majority of situations.

Comment: i use h1 cause h1s font-size is higher then span default text size so if he don't style it at least he can see the difference between before Christmas   and now Christmas

Comment: The semantics of your choice is all wrong. `<h1>` is a top level heading that should briefly describe the topic of the section it introduces. The word _"Christmas!"_ is not a heading in this context. You shouldn't base what element you use on a browser's default **visual** rendering. Base it on how well it **describes** the content. If you have paragraphs of text and you want a border around each one would you use `<fieldset>`instead of `<p>` (by default fieldset has a broder)? No, paragraphs are not fieldsets. CSS is for making stylistic changes/choices, not HTML.